# How to create a windows executable which starts a command?

Tags: windows

I would like to have a windows executable (.exe-file) which starts a given command. The command to execute would be stored in an .ini-file (or something similar) in the same directory as the executable.

It needs to work on XP, Vista and Win7.

What is the easiest way to get such an executable with open source tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a batch file (.bat) and use a [Batch to Exe converter](http://download.cnet.com/Bat-To-Exe-Converter/3000-2069_4-10555897.html) to convert it to an .exe file.

The batch file contains the following commands:

```
@echo off
set /p var= <MyCommand.txt
%var%
exit
```

And MyCommand.txt contains your command, for example:

```
"notepad.exe"
```

The batch file reads the command from the text file and runs it. And if you don't want a .bat then convert it to .exe. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [tool called IExpress](http://renegadetech.blogspot.com/2006/07/how-to-convert-bat-file-or-vbs-file.html) that converts batch files or vb scripts to exe files. I haven't tried it, but it seems to be what you want.